Can I assign a callable to a std::function with a different return type?
I want to store a function inside a std::function. I don't care about the return value when calling this stored function, so the std::function just returns void.
Is there any undefined behavior when the stored function gets called?
Take the following example as a reference, where the function is a lambda returning an int (Link to run):
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
std::function<void(void)> f;
int main()
{
    f = []() -> int { std::cout << "Returning int\n";  return 0; };
    f(); // Is this UB in any way?
    return 0;
}

The question applies not only to lambdas, but to any callable, such as member functions, free functions, etc.

I think it is valid and the return value is simply discarded, but I cannot quote the standard on that.

fwiw, std::function::operator== has all the information it needs. If this wasnt allowed there would be no need or gain to make it undefined, it could be a plain readable compiler error.

@cigien Thanks for your edit, but however, my question is not limited to lambdas. It also applies to free standing functions and also member functions by proper bind.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: I cannot see why operator== would be relevant.  No one is comparing between two std::function objects here.

@BenVoigt typo. operator=

Ignoring the return result is explicitly allowed.
You are using the template< class F > function& operator=( F&& f ); overload of operator=, which has the requirement:

This operator does not participate in overload resolution unless f is Callable for argument types Args... and return type R.

Which is

INVOKE<R>(f, std::declval<ArgTypes>()...) is well-formed in unevaluated context.

And std::function<R(Args...>::operator()(Args... args) is similarly defined as doing INVOKE<R>(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...), returning nothing in the case R is void.

The exposition-only operation INVOKE<R>(f, arg_0, arg_1, arg_2, ..., arg_N) is defined as follows:

If R is (possibly cv-qualified) void

static_cast<void>(INVOKE(f, arg_0, arg_1, arg_2, ..., arg_N)).




I.e. it explicitly discards the result by casting to void

That's a good explanation. Happy to see that sometimes what seems like common sense is actually defined like that in C++  ;-)

This is valid code, the return will simply be discarded.
However, it is difficult to tell on a swift inspection if this was intentional or an oversight.
Clarifying that this  was your intention with tools such as std::ignore will help the readability of your code
auto g =  []() -> int { std::cout << "Returning int\n";  return 0; };

f = [&g]() -> void{ std::ignore = g(); };

//use g somewhere else or refactor to eliminate g


Capturing g by reference is dangerous if f escapes local scope, which is the case in the question.  So "refactor to eliminate g" is the correct answer there, not using it elsewhere.  Although another valid option is to move-capture it instead.
